# How to Run ROS 1 / ROS2 in frdmrobotics/playground in Docker on Windows and Connect via VcXsrv

Tags: windows, docker, ros

I am trying to run the frdmrobotics/playground Docker Image like in this tutorial.
And also Connect the Gui via VcXsrv.

I tried to pull the Image but already only got errors.
Also I have no idea how I should connect VcXsrv from inside the Image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem with Pulling was solved by updating Docker for Windows by starting it and letting it search for an Update. 
After a Restart I could Pull the image with docker pull frdmrobotics/playground.

For starting a Container of the Image

```
docker run -it frdmrobotics/playground
```

works, but from the Tutorial
cd to the desired development folder e.g.

```
cd c:/rosProgramming
```

and then use:

```
docker run -dt --name robot_env --restart unless-stopped -v %cd%:/root/workspace frdmrobotics/playground
```

That starts the Container which can then be connected to by using:

```
docker exec -it robot_env bash
```

For Connecting VcXsrv I found the Info that I had to set some things in the Image:

export DISPLAY=192.168.105.1:0.0
export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1

The needed IP Address in that command I got via ipconfig, it is the one which is marked with "(WSL)".
After that when I started a Programm it Opened in my VcXsrv Instance

After that you can use:

```
cd /root/code/ros1
```

to navigate to the ros1 environment